# how to inflate layout as drawable in map android?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-api-2

I want to show my layout as marker on google map but it can not inflate on map. can anyone help me to solve this. and i use polaris library. My code is written below:

```
final View altMarker = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.map_view, null);

        altMarker.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        altMarker.buildDrawingCache();

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(altMarker.getDrawingCache());

    final ArrayList<Annotation> annotations = new ArrayList<Annotation>();
        for (Annotation[] region : sRegions) {
            for (Annotation annotation : region) {
                if (region == sFrance || region == sIndia) {
                    annotation.setMarker(drawable);
                }
                annotations.add(annotation);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(altMarker.getWidth(), altMarker.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```